# БД SQL запрос join

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Всем привет!

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Есть у меня 2 таблички в базе. Связаны между собой по ключу.
Объедению их так для вывода:

```
SELECT * FROM drivers INNER JOIN buses ON drivers.id_buses = buses.id
```

Все отлично, выводит результат в таблицу.

Как теперь эту таблицу сохранить?

Задача какая, надо из 2 таблиц создать новую.

---

За ранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * into new_table FROM drivers INNER JOIN buses ON drivers.id_buses = buses.id
```

Comment: спасибо! Работает. Короткий запрос и все обрабатывает

Answer (score 0):

При условии, что водители и автобусы связаны 1:1, то в `SELECT` в нужном порядке укажите поля, которые должны будут попасть в новую таблицу. Порядок должен быть тот же, что и в новой таблице. [Документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
    SELECT 
        drivers.id, 
        drivers.нужное_поле_1, 
        ...
        drivers.нужное_полеN, 
        buses.нужное поле1, 
        ...
        buses.нужное_полеN 
   FROM 
       drivers 
   INNER JOIN buses ON drivers.id_buses = buses.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl AS SELECT...
```